# Flutter Dropdown with radio button

Tags: flutter, radio-button, dropdown

**How to Design this type of `Dropdown`** [dropdown with radio button - sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJj6d.jpg)

I will tryed more time of this design.. and if I select one option it sohwes only `Text`

**My Code**

````
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        value: selectedVtypes,
                        items: ['New', 'Pre-Owned'].map((String value) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: Container(
                              width: 150,
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(value),
                                trailing: Radio(
                                  value: value,
                                  groupValue: value,
                                  onChanged: (val) {},
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            value: value,
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (String? vtype) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedVtypes = vtype;

                            
                          });
                        },
                        
                      ),
                    ),```
````

Comment: https://codesinsider.com/flutter-dropdown-button-example/

Comment: That is helpful.. but I need Radio button inside a `dropDownMenuItem`....

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_select